# Xcode asset catalogs: Why doesn't the "Appearances" option apply to tvOS’s interface style trait?

Tags: xcode, tvos, asset-catalog

The interface appearance on tvOS can be either dark or light, described by `UITraitCollection`’s `userInterfaceStyle` property. So I’d like to include two versions of an image asset — a dark one, and a light one — and use whichever is appropriate for the current interface style.

In an asset catalog, image assets in can be varied for dark or light appearances using the “Appearances” field in the inspector. I figured that `UIImage`’s `imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:` method would pick the appearance variant of the asset by matching the appearance property of the trait collection and the appearance variant of the asset, but if selecting anything other than “None” from the “Appearances” menu forces a “Universal” device variant of the asset, instead of just an “Apple TV” variant. That makes me think that the “Appearances” field applies only to macOS’s interface appearance trait for some reason.

So, since the asset catalog won’t let me add appearance variants for Apple TV, it seems `imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:` doesn’t account for the trait collection’s `userInterfaceStyle` at all. I can’t find any documentation about whether or not it’s supposed to.

Can anyone confirm that this is the expected behavior, or am I overlooking something?